# How to detect valid URLs in go?

Tags: go

I wanted to try check for valid urls when i enter it in my program before I send requests to it using the rest API. I used the regexp package in go. The following is my regexp :

```
urlRegex := "^(https?://)[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]"
```

I match it to my input using the `regexp.MatchString()` method.

```
match, _ := regexp.MatchString(urlRegex, args[0])
```

However this gives me a valid url for cases such as `http:////:9000 or http://a.`

Are there any packages in go that I can import for more robust url checking ?

Comment: Read this: https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-how-to-validate-url-the-right-way

Comment: Are you tyring the undoable?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `net/url.Parse()`.

```
 import (
         "net/url"
 )

_, err := url.Parse(args[0])
```

Comment: I tried using this. It doesn't give me an error for any of the above cases. For e.g. : url.Parse("////:9000") does not return an  error.

Comment: Since in the above case url is not absolute. There is no protocol given.